# Ordering children in sqlalchemy and/or flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a flask application that shows quiz questions. For this question the following models are important:

```
class Questions(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "questions"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
quiz_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey("quizzes.id"))
text = db.Column(db.String(80))
options = db.relationship("Options", backref="question", lazy="dynamic")

class Options(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "options"

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey("questions.id"))
value = db.Column(db.String(80))
correct = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

In python I query the question and send it to the jinja2 template. In the template, of loop over the options:

```
{% for option in question.options %}
                        <div class="form-check my-3">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="{{ option.id }}"
                                   name="answer" value="{{ option.id }}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ option.id }}"><h3>{{ option }}</h3>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

The result of this will always be the same order of options, based on their ID in the DB.

Want I want is that the options are shown in a random order.So I tried:

```
{% for option in question.options|random %}
```

Now the following errors occurs: TypeError: object of type 'AppenderBaseQuery' has no len()

After this, I have tried to see if I could provide an order in the class of the questions itself. This doesn't work like this, and I also couldn't find anything on other sites. For example:

```
options = db.relationship("Options", backref="question", lazy="dynamic", order="random")
```

I am not sure if I should be able to retrieve the options in a randomly order, of just shuffle the list somehow in the template. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch the options from DB you get a python `list`.
All you need to do is to shuffle it before you render the template.
See the example below

```
import random

options = ['opt7', 'opt14', 'opt21','opt99']
print(options)
random.shuffle(options)
print(options)
```

output

```
['opt7', 'opt14', 'opt21', 'opt99']
['opt21', 'opt99', 'opt14', 'opt7']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, it does not work.The error it returns when I random.shuffle(question.options) is the following:<br>

        question = quiz.get_next_question(quiz, session)
        random.shuffle(question.options)

TypeError: object of type 'AppenderBaseQuery' has no len()

Comment: @ThomasFromTheNetherlands Please explain "it does not work.." Share the code that fetch the data from DB.

Comment: @ThomasFromTheNetherlands: the issue why `shuffle` does not work for you is because you marked the relationship as `lazy=True`. In this case `question.options` is not yet a list with related `Options`, but rather an sqlalchemy query. so in order to shuffle it you can do: `random.shuffle(list(question.options))`.

Comment: Looks like a proper solution - isnt it?

Comment: I will continu experimenting on this one. When I do this: `x = random.shuffle(list(question.options))
        print(x)` It only returns None.

Comment: Yes - random just return None. Do `options_list = list(questions.options)  random.shuffle(options_list)` - u r done :-)